# Lightning Action with the new Flow Builder - Navigate to newly created record by the flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I was able to wire a flow constructed by the new Flow Builder (coming out in Spring'19) to a custom Lightning Action, and this flow sits on opportunity record detail and clones the existing opportunity with a screen to allow users to modify values for certain fields before creating the clone opportunity.

The flow successfully creates the new opportunity. However, it does not drop the user to the newly created opportunity. How can I navigate the users to the newly created opportunity instead of ending on the old opportunity?

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to create a very simple Aura Lightning Component that implements [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) and add it to one final screen in your Flow. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, so would be interested to see any other answers.

You can either add a Lightning Component to a [flow screen](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_intro.htm), or make a Lightning Component available as a [flow action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_actions.htm). Once you've created a Lightning Component that implements the appropriate interface, it'll be available for use in Flow Builder.

Comment: Can you add a lightning component to a screen within a flow? If so, how? Didn’t see that as an option in the Flow Builder.

Comment: I've updated my answer - hope this helps!

Comment: Ah ok, so you think that if I were to create an aura lightning component implementing lightning:availableForFlowActions, then I will be able to reference the cmp from the flow builder? I’ll give that a shot soon and update, thanks!